# TASM program not printing anything

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I wrote a program  for calculating the mean value of an array of integers in TASM, but the console won't display anything, even though the algorithm seems to work fine. 
Does anybody have a clue what the problem is?

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
msg db "The average is:", "$"
sir db 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
lng db $-sir
DATA ENDS


CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
 MAIN PROC FAR
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX    ;initialization part stops here

mov cx, 9
mov ax, 0
mov bx, 0
sum:
add al, sir[bx]  ;for each number we add it to al and increment the nr of 
  ;repetions
inc bx
loop sum

idiv bx

MOV AH, 09H   ;the printing part starts here, first with the text
LEA DX, msg
INT 21H

mov ah, 02h  
mov dl, al    ;and then with the value
int 21h


ret
MAIN ENDP
CODE ENDS
END MAIN
```

Comment: How are you running this? Also, the way you're trying to print the value of `al` won't work. `int 21h/ah=02h` prints a single *character*. If you want to print an integer you'll have to convert the integer into a string a print it with e.g. `int 21h/ah=09h`.

Comment: I'm compiling with the code with TASM, and then running the executable, I'm expecting the answer to appear to the console.

Comment: I get your point, but since in my case the answer is only a digit I thought it would still do the job. However, the string which appears first is also not printed, and the console freezes after I run it.....

Comment: @mihaicata1205 Because your word-sized division operated on a random value in `DX`, you experienced a _divide exception_ (The result couldn't fit in a 16-bit register). That's why nothing got printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> idiv bx
> ```

The word-sized division will divide `DX:AX` by the value in the operand `BX`. Your code did not setup `DX` beforehand!

The **easiest** solution here is to use the byte-sized division `idiv bl` that will divide `AX` by the value in `BL` leaving the quotient in `AL` and the remainder in `AH`.

The very small numbers in the array add up to 45. This will result in a quotient of 5 and a remainder of 0.

---

> ```
> MOV AH, 09H   ;the printing part starts here, first with the text
> LEA DX, msg
> INT 21H
>
> mov ah, 02h  
> mov dl, al    ;and then with the value
> int 21h
> ```

This part of the program has 2 problems.

- By the time you want to use the result from `AL`, it has been destroyed by the DOS system call that will leave with the value `AL="$"`.
- To display the result as a character, you still need to add "0". This will convert from 5 to "5".

---

This solution addresses all these issues:

```
idiv bl
push ax         ;Save quotient in AL

lea dx, msg
mov ah, 09h
int 21h         ;This destroys AL !!!

pop dx          ;Get quotient back straight in DL
add dl, "0"     ;Make it a character
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
```

Answer (score 0):

`idiv bx` divides the 32-bit value in `dx:ax` by `bx`. So prior to the division you need to sign-extend `ax` into `dx`, which you can achieve e.g. with the `cwd` instruction.

Another issue is that you need to add `'0'` to the value in `al` (or `dl`) before `int 21h/ah=02h` in order to convert it into a character. Note that this method only works with single-digit values.

---

You might also want to change that `ret` at the end to `mov ax,4c00h / int 21h`, which is the proper way to exit from a DOS program.